# In MySQL, how do I do a date query?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to do `SELECT count(*) FROM users where created_at within 3 days ago`

Created_at is datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for a date three days ago:

```
WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

Check the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) documentation.

Or you can use:

```
WHERE t.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this answer.  Also, I have another question. How can I select count where Yesterday, where yesterrday - 1, where yesterday - 2, etc, get it?  I want the count for each day... How can I do that? Could you add that to your answer please? thakns.